# как убрать границу в input при виборе но толькло с одной сторони

Tags: html, css

мне надо штоб при виборе инпута небило граници только с лева вот код:

```css
.InputDiv {
    width:calc(100% - 10px);
    height:15vh;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
input{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    font-size:5vh;
}
#input{
    width:calc(100% - 10px - 15vh);
    outline: 0 1;
}
form{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.close-eye{
    position:relative;
    height:15vh;
    width:15vh;
    bottom:15.5vh;
    left:calc(100% - 15vh);
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class = "InputDiv">
    <input type="password" id="input" name="input" placeholder="Network password"/>
    <div id="eye" class="close-eye"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Граница слева должна остаться, а все остальные исчезнуть или наоборот, убрать только левую границу, а все остальные должны быть видны?

Comment: убрать только левую

Comment: Ну допустим так: `#input:focus-visible { border-left: none; outline: none; }` - добавьте это в стили и должно помочь

Comment: спасибо большое очень помогли